# Missing Tables afters running migrate. Script has 219 table to create but after successful migration it shows only 122

Tags: flyway

Using Flyway 4.0.3
I have run many tests and all work fine.
I am trying to migrate my tables and create a script which has 219 table creation script with other permissions, constraints, indexes.

Migration run fine without any error.

However while manual validation i found only 122 tables created. Is there any limit on sql script.

I have tried to run the create table command directly on DB and it creates the table without any error. So there is no issue from DB side wondering if there are any limitation on how many objects we can create in a single script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: 
There was some triggers in the script which need to / at the end to execute the same. This triggered to skip rest create tables. 
there was a warning message but the script was successfull.